# Application stopped working when loading layout with setContentView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, classcastexception

Here's the XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/search_lyt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:name="search_act"
tools:context="com.example.app.Hisp$PlaceholderFragment">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:src="@drawable/hispania_lgs"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:id="@+id/back2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Info"
    android:id="@+id/info2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/model_list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewML"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/back2"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Select any of the models below and press Info for the model's specifications"
    android:id="@+id/textViewML"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/model_list" />
```

And using the setContentView method results in an 'Application stopped working'.

```
setContentView(R.layout.search_hisp);
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I'm quite new to Android Development and still trying to find how to switch layouts the correct way.

Well, even I change the onCreate()' setContentView to R.layout.search_hisp and gave me the error on startup. So my guess is it's probably from the XML file or something.

Thanks in advance!

Edit, there's the error:

>

```
 03-25 12:10:23.415  20858-20858/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
            at com.example.app.Hisp.beginSearch(Hisp.java:121)
            at com.example.app.Hisp$3.onClick(Hisp.java:107)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4231)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17537)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 12:10:23.420      515-550/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.example.app
03-25 12:10:23.420      515-550/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.example.app v1 (1.0)
03-25 12:10:23.420      515-550/? E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: Hisp_Selector
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.UserHandle;
import android.preference.DialogPreference;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Hisp extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static ActionBarActivity activity;

    Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        activity = this;

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hisp);

        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);

        Button btn = (Button) g(R.id.search);
        Button rst = (Button) g(R.id.reset);

        rst.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        OnClickListener _rdb = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R134a)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R22)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R404A)).setChecked(false);
                ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R507A)).setChecked(false);

                ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(true);
            }
        };

        ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R134a)).setOnClickListener(_rdb);
        ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R22)).setOnClickListener(_rdb);
        ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R404A)).setOnClickListener(_rdb);
        ((CheckBox) g(R.id.R507A)).setOnClickListener(_rdb);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                beginSearch();
            }
        });
        /*
        if (stanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        */
    }

    public void beginSearch() {

        ((EditText) g(R.id.rh)).setText("Test##".toCharArray(), 0, "Test##".length());

        Boolean err = false;

        try {

            if (!(Double.parseDouble((((EditText) g(R.id.capacity)).getText().toString().trim())) >= 0 &&
                isBetween(-35, 5, Integer.parseInt(((EditText) g(R.id.evaptemp)).getText().toString().trim()))  &&
                isBetween(28, 58, Integer.parseInt(((EditText) g(R.id.condtemp)).getText().toString().trim())) &&
                isBetween(5, 13, Integer.parseInt(((EditText) g(R.id.dt1)).getText().toString().trim()))
            )) err = true;

        } catch(Exception e) {
            err = true;
        }

        if (err) {
            showMessageBox("ERROR", "Make sure you have filled all the fields correctly.", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.search_hisp);
        }
    }

    public View g(int id) {
        return activity.findViewById(id);
    }

    public Boolean isBetween(Integer i1, Integer i2, Integer ix) {
        if (ix >= i1 && ix <= i2) return true;

        return false;
    }

    public void showMessageBox(Object ttl, Object msg, DialogInterface.OnClickListener rt) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                .setMessage(msg.toString())
                .setTitle(ttl.toString())
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, rt)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hisp, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hisp, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: post the activity code and the stacktrace

Comment: Where is your error ?

Comment: Ah sorry I don't quite know how to retrieve activity code/stacktrace in Android Studio. Any pointers?

Comment: you are casting Textview to EditText dont do that..

Comment: where is your closing tag of your relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in onCreate() you have used

```
 EditText textViewML = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

instead of

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

so you got problem. So you need to use after your setContentView() method.

```
 TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Put in the onCreate :

```
TextView textViewML = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

Comment: Why would that matter though?

Comment: Do you used an EditText ?

Answer (score 1):

The error was from

```
((EditText) g(R.id.rh)).setText("Test##".toCharArray(), 0, "Test##".length());
```

Thanks a lot guys for pointing this out!

Comment: But you log shows this one: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: And somehow I'm lying? The R.id.rh seemed to be the TextView that is being casted. Sorry for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

you are casting Textview to EditText dont do that

```
EditText textViewML = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

change it as

```
TextView textViewML = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exception is not your layout file it is in your java file you are casting TextView into EditText.

You can not Cast Super class in to sub class.
you can cast Sub class into Super Class.

You can Cast EditText into TextView but not TextView in to EditText.

Change this line

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewML);
```

Thanx